# control speakers in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c

Thanks for your time.

I have a doubt regarding the speaker controls in the iPhone . We have two speakers in iPhone:

1. **Ear speaker** ---- When we are talking in phone at the ear we have speaker
2. **Bottom Speaker** ---- When we are playing the music sound comes from bottom speaker

My doubt is: I have taken two UISwitches those are Ear_speaker,Bottom_Speaker.

If I switch on the Ear_speaker while playing ,the sound should come from Ear_speaker only and If I switch off the Ear speaker the sound shouldn't come from the Ear speaker.

Same functionality for Bottom_Speaker also.

Comment: Please read my updated question

Answer (score 2):

Setup your audio session

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
```

Implement it in UISwitch:

This changes audio route to a bottom speaker:

```
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;

AudioSessionSetProperty (
                         kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,
                         sizeof (audioRouteOverride),
                         &audioRouteOverride                                               
                         );
```

This changes audio route to a "Ear speaker":

```
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_None;

AudioSessionSetProperty (
                         kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,
                         sizeof (audioRouteOverride),
                         &audioRouteOverride                                               
                         );
```